# Why when downloading a file in Ruby ​on Rails this one is downloaded with the name TRUE?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

This is my code and ruby ​​on rails download the files with the name "TRUE"

```
<% if @message.document_file_name %>
    <%= link_to @message.document.url, download:true do %>
    <span class="fa fa-download fa-lg"></span>
<% end %>
<% else %>
    No file.
<% end %>
```

Comment: What's the structure of that table? What files?

Comment: can you inspect the generated html and see what the value of `@message.document.url` is?

Comment: the `download` attribute takes a filename, not just `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`download` attribute get a name of needed file

```
= link_to @message.document.url, download: 'file_name'
```

BTW name you can get from your URL to file, if you need native name

if you build link without `download` attribute, your file will open in browser by default